# Some notation in Riemann integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, notation

I'm reading an authoritative source on convex optimization and trying to understand the author's notation. He writes

> It is easy to see that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$
>   $$f'(y)-f'(x)=\int\limits_0^1 f''(x+t(y-x))(y-x)dt.$$

I am embarrassed with the integral above. That's okay if $f$ is defined on the real line, but in general (when $n\geqslant 2$) $f''$ is a $n\times n$-matrix and its Riemann integral is also a matrix, doesn't it? However, the $lhs$ is a vector here.

Could you please clarify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that $f'$ is the gradient, so it is a $n$-vector.

$f''(x+t(y-x))(x-y)$ is the product of an $n\times n$ matrix and a $n$-vector, so it is again a $n$-vector.

Comment: Really, that was the product! Thanks a lot!